# Multi-column join very slow in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have two large tables, `table_1` and `table_2`. Each has columns `id`, `name` and `number`. I want to find the records in `table_1` that have matching names and numbers in `table_2`:

```
select t1.* from table_1 t1, table_2 t2 
where t1.name = t2.name and t1.number = t2.number;
```

Or using the join syntax:

```
select t1.* from table_1 join table_2 on
t1.name = t2.name and t1.number = t2.number;
```

Both are very slow.

I added indexes for `name` and `number` in both tables. Still very slow. I then added a multi column index `(name, number)` on both tables. Still very slow.

Finally, I tried creating a `combined` column in both tables and set its value to `concat(name, number)`. I added indexes in both tables for the `combined` column and then ran the following:

```
select t1.* from table_1 t1, table_2 t2
where t1.combined = t2.combined
```

Super fast!

Isn't there a more elegant way to achieve the performance without the awkward workaround of creating the `combined` column?

Comment: Read about MySQL's `EXPLAIN` feature to learn what index definition do make sense.

Comment: what mean very slow? ten second, ten minute? .. and how  many records there are in each tables ?

Comment: @scaisEdge there are about a million records in each table. Slow in this case is about 10 minutes. I think something is wrong - I am following arkascha's advice and looking at Explain.

Comment: @arkascha - thanks for the reminder about Explain. I am looking at it and I think there is a problem.

Comment: without seeing the tables and maybe a sample of data, its hard to say...Explain would be even better...Combining the two columns seems not necessary. Its hard to say that without knowing for sure what is stored in name and number, but using a composite index where the number is first and the name second, number being more unique, should traverse the BTREE more efficiently...

Comment: @BK435 - thanks for the advice on having the more unique column first in the composite index.

Comment: Sure. Remember that datatypes being the same when doing an ON CLAUSE also makes a difference...As well as the cardinality of the data itself...Name and Number may not be all that unique within the table itself...A million records is not that large at all btw...